# JPA derived delete query for many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm writing an app in Spting Boot with Hibernet. In this app I have two entities: Customer and Coupon with many-to-many relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Coupon> coupons;

@Entity
public class Coupon {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private Integer amount;
    private Double;
```

And yes, I don't want to keep a list of customers in the coupon entity. But this many-to-many relationship works and creates a table in the database with the customer_coupons name.

The question is this. I want to write a derived delete query in the coupon repository that deletes all the rows in their common customer_coupons table. E.g. I want to delete all the purchases of a given coupon.

I have a coupon repository with the derived delete query:

```
@Repository
public interface CouponRepository extends JpaRepository<Coupon, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE customer_coupons cc WHERE cc.coupons_id = :couponId")
    public List<Integer> deletePurchases(int couponId);
}
```

But it doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'couponRepository' defined in com.olga.projectPart2.repository.CouponRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.olga.projectPart2.repository.CouponRepository.deletePurchases(int)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.olga.projectPart2.repository.CouponRepository.deletePurchases(int)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.olga.projectPart2.repository.CouponRepository.deletePurchases(int)!
```

What do I miss? Is it possible or do I need to use a native query? And yes, I don't want to use cascade properties.

Answer (score 0):

*FROM* keyword is missing in the query. The right query would be something like below,

```
  @Query("DELETE FROM CustomerCoupons cc WHERE cc.couponId = :couponId")
```

Comment: It becomes a native query and with the parameter nativeQuery = true it does work. I thought there might be a way to right jpa query but it seems there isn't.

Comment: FROM keyword can be used for JPA/Hibernate queries as well. Your question doesn't have an entity name for "customer_coupons" hence I've referred to the same provided. Updated the above answer by assuming its "CustomerCoupons" is the name of entity, hope it helps. "couponId" value can be set something like, setString("couponId", {value_of_couponId}) method.

Comment: There is no entity for this table. It creates by jpa automatically when creating many-to-many relationship. The name of a table in the database in customer_coupons.